# MSI diff on packages to create patches

Tags: installation, windows-installer, patch

I am looking at what the best options for creating patches for our clients. They don't want a full blown installer when doing minor patches (from 1.0 to 1.1) since they will need to do a full regression on the system.

I wanted to know whether there is a tool (paid or not) that will take 2 msi builds do a diff/compare and out put a useable patch installer.

Most of the time it will be updates to assemblies (modified or new) but may require some custom script (in c# if possible)

Answer (score 3):

> They don't want a full blown installer when doing minor patches... since they will need to do a full regression on the system.

This statement is based on some faulty logic and whoever uttered it is blowing smoke out the proverbial. There is every bit as much risk from a patch install as what there is from a full installer - if the testers have no faith in your build/release process then both need to be tested fully. The msi is just the **packaging**, a full install or a patch install can both change the whole system. If the testers want to come up with the argument that *"with the patch, the file abc.dll has not changed so we don't have to test the functionality in it"*, then you can argue that that thinking is incorrect - if the code using abc.dll has changed then abc.dll may exhibit different behaviour.

IOW, my argument is that a patch install or full install both carry the same level of risk, and both should be tested to the same level. To minimize the amount of retesting required you need to build trust and certainty with your release process - an automated build/release process and an auditable source control system should do that for you.

In any case, i agree withthe answer from @Christopher - tools such as InstallShield can be used to create a single msi that is either a full install if you haven't already got the product on your machine, or it will switch to upgrade mode if it detects an item with the same product code and a lesser version number already installed. Having said that, it can be incredibly difficult to get that upgrade to work correctly.

Comment: I agree 100% however we are dealing with their internal policies. they need to see files have not been replaced by the installer (our full installer will do that).

Comment: ROFLMAO. Agree 100% but sadly you may or may not be suprised how many times I've heard it uttered from so many people over the past 15 years. But I disagree that the risk between full and patch is the same.  A patch install is *MORE* risk because your full install process is fully automated and your patch definition process is not.  It's like practicing the same way over and over then when it comes time to release you call an audible and do it another way.

Comment: BTW, depending on how you define the "Build/Release Process", I may disagree with that point also.  In my experience the build/release process is 100% bullet proof.  The problem is more on the SCM side on how locked down the baseline is.   Typically it's not a build problem, it's more of a problem that they either don't know what's been checked in or they know too much has been checked in and they are now trying to work around it by creating a patch installer.

Comment: @user551962 - if your installer is replacing files that shouldn't be replaced, then that's a problem with your setup logic.

Comment: Sascha- Define "shouldn't be".  Maybe they did a full build instead of an incremental build so the installer see's 'new' files that in reality didn't have any meaningful changes.

Answer (score 2):

InstallShield can do this provided:

1. You follow strict compliance with the component rules and have a working minor upgrade servicing story.
2. You are incrementally building your assemblies as to not make the system think all of your files changed.

There are other ways to accomplish this but it takes quite a bit of plumbing to be honest.

To be honest, I've heard your "we have to test it all" story many times and I've never bought the argument.  Usually they want to piece-meal their baseline and then stick their head in the sand on what the true test surface is.  Usually their real problem is one of SCM / Build / Release discipline and not whether the installer is a Major Upgrade, Minor Upgrade or Patch.  ( IMO )

Comment: I agree about test all or not however they are a Bank and have internal policies we have to live with. I will look at InstallShield thanks.

Comment: InstallShield also has a QuickPatch pattern.  I've never found a way to automate it but if you release cycle isn't that frequent it might do what you want.  Basically  you feed it 1 MSI and then select a bunch of files and it will generate an MSP for just those files.   So if you are told once a month or so that we need to patch these 5-10 files ( you get the point )  this might work for you.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is it is at least once a week and the process is rather manual at the moment and error prone. Thanks for your help.